# Getting an array for chart

Tags: ruby

I had 10 items in total. I lost all of them in 3 days: 5 items on the 1st day, 3 items on the 2nd day, and 2 items on the last day. I need to get an array `[5, 2, 0]` of remaining items at the end of each day. How can I get the array, given total `10` and the array of lost items `[5, 3, 2]`?

Comment: please show your efforts and where you got stuck! See [ask] and provide a [mcve] as [so] is not a (homework) coding service!

Comment: You need to give us examples of your inputs and structure of your code

Comment: Just switch to Haskell, and your function is `tail . scanl (-) 10` \o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[5, 3, 2].each_with_object([10]){|e, a| a.push(a.last - e)}.drop(1)
# => [5, 2, 0]
```

Know why you need the complication `drop(1)`? It is because, without it, the answer makes more logical sense. Your requirement is what was complicated.

```
[5, 3, 2].each_with_object([10]){|e, a| a.push(a.last - e)}
# => [10, 5, 2, 0]
```

The initial `10` represents the initial state.

Comment: Yes! That's what I was looking for, thank you!